# Generic Map/Reduce List Extensions in C#

Tags: c#, functional-programming, extension-methods

I am writing a few extensions to mimic the map and reduce functions in Lisp.

```
public delegate R ReduceFunction<T,R>(T t, R previous);
public delegate void TransformFunction<T>(T t, params object[] args);

public static R Reduce<T,R>(this List<T> list, ReduceFunction<T,R> r, R initial)
{
     var aggregate = initial;
     foreach(var t in list)
         aggregate = r(t,aggregate);

     return aggregate;
}
public static void Transform<T>(this List<T> list, TransformFunction<T> f, params object [] args)
{
    foreach(var t in list)
         f(t,args);
}
```

The transform function will cut down on cruft like:

```
foreach(var t in list)
    if(conditions && moreconditions)
        //do work etc
```

Does this make sense? Could it be better?

Comment: This already exists. Take a look at C# 3 / LINQ.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense.  The answers to this question and several others show an *astonishing* lack of understanding what a reduce function is.  Yes, the output type is supposed to be independent of the input type.  `Aggregate` is *not* a reduce function, as so many people have claimed.  Maybe that's why they called it something different.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

These look very similar to extensions in Linq already:

```
//takes a function that matches the Func<T,R> delegate
listInstance.Aggregate( 
    startingValue, 
    (x, y) => /* aggregate two subsequent values */ );

//takes a function that matches the Action<T> delegate
listInstance.ForEach( 
    x => /* do something with x */);
```

Why is the 2nd example called Transform? Do you intend to change the values in the list somehow? If that's the case you may be better off using `ConvertAll<T>` or `Select<T>`.

Comment: The C++ standard library has `std::transform` which does just that. Here's a [link to std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

Comment: @RAM I suppose that would be a C++ equivalent to `Select`, but templates in C++ and generics in C# are very different. In addition this OP is asking about functional programming, so the extension method can take an immutable collection and output an immutable collection. In C++ this takes a one range as input and mutates a second range as output, which is more of an OO approach.

Answer (score 54):

According to this link [Functional Programming in C# 3.0: How Map/Reduce/Filter can Rock your World](http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/2008/06/16/FunctionalProgrammingInC30HowMapReduceFilterCanRockYourWorld.aspx) the following are the equivalent in C# under the System.Linq namespace:

- map    --> [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx)
- reduce --> [Enumerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate.aspx)
- filter --> [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I would use the built in Func delegates instead.  This same code would work on any IEnumerable.  Your code would turn into:

```
public static R Reduce<T,R>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T,R> r, R initial)
{
     var aggregate = initial;
     foreach(var t in list)
         aggregate = r(t,aggregate);

     return aggregate;
}
public static void Transform<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T> f)
{
    foreach(var t in list)
             f(t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add a way to do a map but return a new list, instead of working on the list passed in (and returning the list can prove useful to chain other operations)... perhaps an overloaded version with a boolean that indicates if you want to return a new list or not, as such:

```
public static List<T> Transform<T>(this List<T> list, TransformFunction<T> f,
        params object [] args)
{
    return Transform(list, f, false, args);
}

public static List<T> Transform<T>(this List<T> list, TransformFunction<T> f,
        bool create, params object [] args)
{
    // Add code to create if create is true (sorry,
    // too lazy to actually code this up)
    foreach(var t in list)
         f(t,args);
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to create extension methods that internally use LinQ [like this](https://github.com/cs-util-com/cscore/blob/master/CsCore/PlainNetClassLib/src/Plugins/CsCore/com/csutil/collections/IEnumerableExtensions.cs):

```
public static IEnumerable<R> Map<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, R> selector) {
    return self.Select(selector);
}

public static T Reduce<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, T, T> func) {
    return self.Aggregate(func);
}

public static IEnumerable<T> Filter<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    return self.Where(predicate);
}
```

Here some example usages:

```
IEnumerable<string> myStrings = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
IEnumerable<int> convertedToInts = myStrings.Map(s => int.Parse(s));
IEnumerable<int> filteredInts = convertedToInts.Filter(i => i <= 3); // Keep 1,2,3
int sumOfAllInts = filteredInts.Reduce((sum, i) => sum + i); // Sum up all ints
Assert.Equal(6, sumOfAllInts); // 1+2+3 is 6
```

(See https://github.com/cs-util-com/cscore#ienumerable-extensions for more examples)